# Use of _inherit and _name for the same model will only create table or will also copy its methods(Functions)?

Tags: odoo

I read an answer about this scenario, the link is bellow

https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/the-different-openerp-model-inheritance-mechanisms-what-s-the-difference-between-them-and-when-should-they-be-used-46​

Specifically to my question the above answer explains

If your class _inherit one model and you set a _name different it will create a new model in a new database table.
 So my question is, this approach will create(inherit) the methods of inherited model as well or I have to define all the methods again?

Comment: You should try to ref this link about inheritance https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/orm.html#inheritance-and-extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the methods and fields will be copied to new model when you will use _inherit and _name both.

Comment: and what about the relations to the other tables?

Comment: Are you asking about relational fields?

Comment: Yes i am asking about relational fields

Comment: You will have all the fields available in new model.